# Bundling doesn't seems to load Bootstrap files in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap in my ASP.NET MVC 4 project.
Following is my bundling code.

```
bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap/scripts").IncludeDirectory("~/bootstrap/js/", "*.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap/css").IncludeDirectory("~/bootstrap/css/", "*.css"));
```

I am using these two bundles along with other specific bundles in various pages.
The problem is that, I can see bootstrap files loading up well in IE, but it doesn't load up in Firefox and Chrome. I have both full and minified versions in JS and CSS directories of bootstrap folder.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you compare the rendered HTML for IE, Chrome and FF to make sure they are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my mistake,I had used "ScriptBundle" to add CSS.. a copy-paste error!